# Swift Array containing closures

Tags: swift, closures

I wrote a state machine `class` and added the possibility to add an `onChange` handler:

```
private var handlers = [((UserState) -> Void)]()

func onChange(handler: @escaping ((UserState) -> Void)) {
    self.handlers.append(handler)
}

func changeState(to newState: UserState) {
    print($0.self)
    $0(newState)
}
```

And I am adding a change listener like this in a view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UserStateMachine.shared.onChange { newState in
        self.setIcon(newState.premium)
    }
}
```

Is the closure now owned by the view controller which added it or by the state machine? Do I have to add weak references to the `handlers` elements?

Comment: That depends. Do you want your controller to be ever released? If yes, then you really need to use `[weak self]`.

Comment: By the way, this is something that could be easily solved using notifications. You are basically reimplementing notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question very directly, the closure is owned by your state machine class. The state machine is what retains the closure and the closure captures a strong reference to your view controller.

Yes, you will need to add a weak reference here since your shared state machine appears to be a singleton that will live forever, unless you had some mechanism for deregistering and removing the closures before the view controller was dismissed.

It rarely makes sense for a singleton to be retaining references to view controllers, however, so I would recommend adding a `[weak self]`.

Answer (score 1):

You capturing the `self` in escaping closure, so yes, you should handle this situation with `weak` (or `unowned`).

Also, you can check if the controller `deinit`s with no problem (i.e. controller calls the `deinit`) - all closures in controller properly handled. If `deinit` never called - you should think about missing `weak`/`unowned` in available closures.